# Save sections of text data to arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, dynamic-arrays

I have data to looks has the following format.  I'd like to create a new 2 column array for each "ran" with the respective ran name after the :.

```
Ran:    Efg    (space between : and E)
1       50     (tab delimited)
2       52     (tab delimited)
3       54     (tab delimited)
Ran:    pg2    (space between : and E)
1       40     (tab delimited)
2       60     (tab delimited)
3       80     (tab delimited)
Ran:    2      (space between : and E)
1       14     (tab delimited)
2       15     (tab delimited)
3       16     (tab delimited)
```

So far, I've a problem with using the following because it gives me an infinite loop, but I'm not sure how else to access the string resulttext from a previous

```
public void openDVHToolStripMenuItem_Click (object sender, EventArgs e){....}

public static string resulttext
    {
        get { return resulttext; }
    }
```

Secondly, I've got the following so far to separate the name of the array-to-be.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> Darray = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(resulttext))
        {
            string line;
            string ran = "Ran:";
            string region = "";

            while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
            {
                if (line.Contains(ran))
                {
                    string[] splitHeader = line.Split(":".ToCharArray());
                    region = splitHeader[1].Trim();
                }
               else
               {
                   if (!line.Contains(ran))
                   {
                       List<string> Dlist = new List<string>();
                       Darray.Add(region, Dlist);
                    }

                }

            }
            foreach (var item in Darray)
            {
                richTextBox2.AppendText(item + Environment.NewLine);
            }

        }


    }
```

I have to be able to call each array later and do some basic math on the values from both columns of numbers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what gives you an infinite loop?

Comment: why not read the entire file into a List<T> or Tuple and then once you set up the correct line of code that Splits() on the specified delim then decide how you want to loop thru the collection and process. I would suggest looking up how to load a file into a List<T> of Dictionary or HashSet, HashList, HashTable ect.. there are so many options then process the data from there..

Comment: @selman22, using the get { return resulttext; } caused visual studio to give me a message stating it was an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
public static string resulttext
{
    get { return resulttext; }
}
```

gives you an “infinite loop” because it is recursive; `return resulttext` calls `public static string resulttext`. Do this:

```
public static string ResultText { get; private set; }
```